# What are the best options for parsing an email message?

Tags: document-library, email, 2007, workflow, development

So I have a document library setup to accept incoming emails. As I can see from the library's columns, there are a number of fields that I can leverage for information (i.e. E-Mail CC, etc) for workflow. However, conspicuously lacking is the Email Body. Has anyone here had the opportunity to extract this bit of information from an email to a document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint doesn't parse the body into a column 'out-of-the-box'.

You would need something like a workflow that runs when new items are created or catch the [event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.emailreceived%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with [custom development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.spemailmessage_members%28v=office.12%29.aspx).